# how do we specify an ssh default identity?

Tags: ssh

id_rsa is normally a default key.

I've created a new key named 'keyhello'

Update:
I've also added this key by doing:

```
ssh-add /home/myuser/.ssh/keyhello
```

But I believe it still isn't my default key.

So, how can we put keyhello to be the default identity, instead of the id_rsa ?

I do see a -t but I've tried:

```
ssh-agent /home/mysuser/.ssh/keyhello -t
```

No luck with this. I get a "Permission Denied" (if I put sudo ssh-agent ... I got the same "Permission Denied w/out even prompt me my sudo pass).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In your ~/.ssh/config file put:

```
IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/keyhello
```

which will tell the outgoing ssh connections to use that as the default identity

Comment: Go it. If the config file doesn't exist. I must create it.

Answer (score 11):

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id will use the last created file that match id_*.pub. To change which one is default just touch it.

```
me@my-machine:~/.ssh$ touch id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: You might need to use `ssh-add -D` after touching, before retrying ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 7):

You can specify an alternate keyfile on the command line with the `-i` option, or you can change it permanently with `IdentityFile` in the ssh client config file.

Answer (score 0):

In my file `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id` at line 59:

```
most_recent_id="$(cd "$HOME" ; ls -t .ssh/id*.pub 2>/dev/null | grep -v -- '-cert.pub$' | head -n 1)"

DEFAULT_PUB_ID_FILE="${most_recent_id:+$HOME/}$most_recent_id"
```

The most recent file will be the default, and you can probably change this. Note that your file must start with 'id'.

Answer (score -5):

if you want to change the default one you send, change `id_*.pub` to to `keyhello.pub` in file `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id`. You will find that on line 60 or something.  The line starts with `DEFAULT_PUB_ID_FILE` and you will see after that `"$HOME/$(cd "$HOME" ; ls -t .ssh/id_*.pub"`.

Comment: Seriously?  The only way this user can make a configuration change that affects them (and only them) is to modify a system file (potentially affecting all the users on the system)?  Is your answer better than the other (6½-year-old) answers to this question?