# How to configure SSH private key for Fork on Mac?

Tags: mac, git

I tried Fork for my Git client on Mac!
Can some one guide me how to configure my existed SSH private key for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fork on Mac will use whatever the default ssh key is, which normally is called id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.  If you created a key with a different name you can set it as the default key by updating (or creating if one doesnt exist) your .ssh/config file with:

`IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/keyhello`

Make sure you're specifying the private key here, not the public one (I made that mistake for some reason and you end up getting an invalid format error).

On my Mac i kept getting complaints that the permissions on the keys were too great so I did a chmod 600 on both files which fixed that issue.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/263405/how-do-we-specify-an-ssh-default-identity/263419) for more about the default key.

Just note that if you do this anything that uses ssh will now try to use this key if you dont specify otherwise.  ie: if youre using the ssh command line you'll need to specify -i to change keys.

It would be much better if Fork had this configurable like their Windows version does.

Answer (score 0):

On every system, SSH keys are located in the users home directory, in a subfolder called `.ssh`.
It is this way on every operating system and all you need to do is to choose one from the list provided by fork.

- Windows: %userprofile%\.ssh
- Linux: ~/.ssh
- Mac: $HOME/.ssh

Simply put your key there and you are fine.